# Secure coding on send and receive data from C sockets. What kind of checks should I perform?

Tags: c, sockets, secure-coding

I'm programming an application that uses C sockets. I perform some check both on `send()` and `recv()` (see the code below) but I'm not sure that they alone are sufficient. What other checks should be performed to secure-code C sockets?

```
ssize_t nbytes;
void send_stuff(int socket_fd, TYPE stuff, size_t EXP_BYTES){
  nbytes = send(socket_fd, (void*)stuff, EXP_BYTES, 0);
  if(nbytes < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in sending stuff from socket %d. Error: %s\n", socket_fd, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }
  if((unsigned long) nbytes < EXP_BYTES){
    fprintf(stderr, "Stuff not entirely sent on socket %d. Error: %s\n", socket_fd, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

Same thing for `recv()`, mutatis mutandis

Comment: Depends what you mean by "secure". Your code has a little to do with security, just a sanity.

Comment: Yes, it has. But confidentiality, integrity, authentication, etc, etc are out of the scope of my question. I'm referring to code sanitization to remove its possible vulnerabilities

Comment: The computer only does what you tell it to. You don't have to tell it not to do the wrong thing. You only have to not tell it to do the wrong thing. Most "insecure code" is a mistake, where the thing the programmer told the computer to do was something stupid. For example, here you're telling it to give up if the whole message isn't sent in one go. So an attacker can crash your program by deliberately making a slow connection. Is that something you want?

Comment: There is no "removing possible vulnerabilities". There are vulnerabilities, and there is code without vulnerabilities. Lists of possible vulnerabilities are useful, so you can check that you haven't accidentally written one. But you can't remove vulnerabilities if there are none!

Comment: Is this for a TCP socket or UDP? If the former, you need to be prepared for reads that are smaller than your expected size - it's normal for that to happen, not an error.

Comment: Maybe I've not been clear enough. I'm referring to those good practices and checks to sanitize code. I would suggest you [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Secure-Coding-2nd-Software-Engineering/dp/0321822137) or [SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c) to get an idea of what I'm talking

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding md5sum. MD5 is 128-bit cryptographic hash and if used properly it can be used to verify file authenticity and integrity.

```
char *str = buffer;
unsigned char digest[16];

    while (length > 0) {
        if (length > 512)
            MD5_Update(&md5, str, 512);
        else
            MD5_Update(&md5, str, length);
        length -= 512;
        str += 512;
    }

    MD5_Final(digest, &md5);
```

You can then add md5sum to end of the buffer and send it along the data

```
char *out = (char *) malloc(33);
    int n;
    for (n = 0; n < 16; ++n) {
        snprintf(&(out[n * 2]), 16 * 2, "%02x",
             (unsigned int) digest[n]);
    }
for (i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        buffer[msgsize + i + 1] = out[i];
    }
```

Then on the other side (server), you can extract the md5sum, calculate it again and compare it md5sum calculated at that side.

```
int n;
    for (n = 0; n < 33; n++) {
        md5recv[n] = buffer[msgsize + n + 1];
    }
```

//OR if exact msg size is not known

```
int n;
    for (n=0; n <33; n--) {
        md5recv[n] = buffer[msgsize -33+n];
    }
```

Then calculate the md5sum for the received data, and compare it with one in the `md5recv[]`.